# How do i set focus on an invalid input field

Tags: laravel

I have an input; it's a string type of input. When I put an invalid input on it, I want it to focus on that invalid input field because the input is wrong, and I have to do a correct input on that invalid input field. How do I do it??

```
<form action="{{url('/store')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>NIK</label>
        <input type="text" id="kredit_nik" name="kredit_nik" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"
               value="{{old('kredit_nik')}}" placeholder="Contoh : 3152021502002002">
    </div>
    @if ($errors->first('kredit_nik'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{$errors->first('kredit_nik')}}</div>
    @endif
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nama Lengkap</label>
        <input type="text" id="kredit_name" name="kredit_name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"
               value="{{old('kredit_name')}}" placeholder="Contoh : Nathanael Budiman">
    </div>
    @error ('kredit_name')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
    <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel's provided [@error](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#the-at-error-directive) blade directive to check if the validation error exists for an input/attribute and combine it with Bootstrap's [error](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/#server-side) class as:

```
@error('input-name') is-invalid @enderror
```

Example:

```
<input type="text" required class="form-control @error('input-name') is-invalid @enderror" name="input-name" id="input-name" value="{{ old('input-name') }}">
```

---

Now, to scroll to the error field you can use jquery to scroll to the first error field:

*Add this before the closing `</body>` tag:*

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var errors = $('.is-invalid')
        if (errors.length) {
            $(document).scrollTop(errors.offset().top)
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Scrolling code is partially taken from:** https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/52#issuecomment-71472662 (original credit)

Comment: Thank you for answering, i tried this one but it doesn't send me back to the invalid input field. What i want, is when i do an invalid input on that input field, it send me back to that input field

Comment: @Nicho you can check the edited answer.

Comment: @Nicho learn and enjoy ;)

Comment: Thank you so much sir, your solution really help :D